# Combining multiple variances weighted by probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, standard-deviation

How do you calculate the overall variance of a situation where there are multiple possible events with known probabilities, and each event has a different and known variance (and expected value)?

As an example, imagine there are three possible carnival games you can play. Each has its own expected value of $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$. Each has its own variance of  $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$. You roll a fair die to determine which game you're going to play. If the roll is a 1, you play game 1. If the roll is a 2 or 3, you play game 2. If the roll is a 4, 5, or 6, you play game 3.

What is the variance of this situation?

I would think you just do a weighted average of the three variances. However, that doesn't make sense for the trivial case where all three games have a variance of zero (they always cost/pay a fixed amount) because the weighted average of the variances would be zero, but clearly the overall situation has a non-zero variance with the different expected values for the different games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would think you just do a weighted average of the three variances. However, that doesn't make sense for the trivial case where all three games have a variance of zero (they always cost/pay a fixed amount) because the weighted average of the variances would be zero, but clearly the overall situation has a non-zero variance with the different expected values for the different games.

Indeed.   Good work in thinking twice about this.   It is just a little more involved.   There's is an additional component to the total variance.

---

Let us take $G$ as number for the game, and $R$ as the result for the game.   We are given these measures:

$$\mathsf E(R\mid G)=E_1{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=1}+E_2{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=2}+E_3{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=3}\\\mathsf{Var}(R\mid G)=V_1{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=1}+V_2{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=2}+V_3{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{G=3}\\\mathsf P(G{=}g)=\tfrac 16{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{g=1}+\tfrac 13{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{g=2}+\tfrac 12{\cdot}\mathbf 1_{g=3}$$

---

So you should know how to find the Expectation of the Result by the Law of Total Expectation:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(R)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(R\mid G))\\[1ex]&=\sum_g \mathsf P(G{=}g)\cdot\mathsf E(R\mid G{=}g)\\[1ex]&=\tfrac 16 E_1+\tfrac 13 E_2+\tfrac 12E_3\end{align}$$

---

**What you want** is to find the Variance of the Result, and to do so you likewise use the Law of Total Variance

$$\mathsf {Var}(R)=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(R\mid G))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(R\mid G))$$

Now, just apply the definitions for expectation and variance.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(R\mid G))&=\sum_g \mathsf P(G{=}g)\cdot\mathsf {Var}(R\mid G{=}g)\\[1ex]&= \phantom{\tfrac 16V_1+\tfrac 13V_2+\tfrac 12V_3}\\[3ex]\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(R\mid G))&=\sum_g \mathsf P(G{=}g)\cdot\mathsf E(R\mid G{=}g)^2-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(R\mid G))^2\\[1ex]&=\phantom{\tfrac 16E_1^2+\tfrac 13E_2^2+\tfrac 12E_3^2-\big(\tfrac 16E_1+\tfrac 13E_2+\tfrac 12E_3\big)^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Remark: $\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(R\mid G))$, the *expected variance of the results for the given games*, is what @MikeFisher originally thought the answer might be, but rejected when he realised something was missing.  $\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(R\mid G))$ the *variance of the expected results for the games* is the missing component.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer (and all the answers here). I found your explanation easy to follow for someone who doesn't have a deep understanding of variance. I was unaware of the law of total variance, which seems useful. The last section of your answer has two parts that are hidden by "phantom" commands. Was that intentional? Because those are the lines that helped me understand the best (assuming they are correct). That is:

$$\mathsf{Var}(R)=\tfrac 16V_1+\tfrac 13V_2+\tfrac 12V_3+\tfrac 16E_1^2+\tfrac 13E_2^2+\tfrac 12E_3^2-(\tfrac 16 E_1+\tfrac 13 E_2+\tfrac 12E_3)^2$$

Comment: Is it OK if I edit your answer to unhide the missing lines? Can you confirm you intended those to be seen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the weighted average $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ of the first two moments $\mu_{1,k}$ and $\mu_{2.k}=V_k+\mu_{1,k}^2$ and then compute the variance $V=\mu_2-\mu_1^2$

$\mu_1=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 k\mu_{1,k}}{6}$
$\mu_2=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 k\mu_{2,k}}{6}$

Note that the example your questioned. $V=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 (k\mu_{1,k})^2}{6}-(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 k\mu_{1,k}}{6})^2\ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

The situation you stated can be described by the following setup:

we have three random variables $X_1, X_2,X_3$ representing the three games with respective expected value and variance. Additionally we define a fourth random variable, say $N$, which is independent (I assume rolling the die is independent of the other games)  of the other three and represents the die you roll. We are interested in $Var(X_N)$.

Now let's start with the expected value of $X_N$:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_N] = \sum_{k=1}^{3} \mathbb{E}[X_N \mathbb{1}\{N=k\}]
=\sum_{k=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}(N=k) \mathbb{E}[X_k] 
$$
where we used the independence of $N$. Similarly we get for the second moment
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_N^2] 
=\sum_{k=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}(N=k) \mathbb{E}[X_k^2]. 
$$
So in both cases the idea of using weighted sums works out, but remember that we use the squared expectation in the formula for the variance.
Therefore, in total the above yields
$$
Var(X_N) = \sum_{k=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}(N=k) \mathbb{E}[X_k^2] - \left( \sum_{k=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}(N=k) \mathbb{E}[X_k]  \right)^2.
$$
Now plug in the probability mass function of $N$ i.e. the die and the respective values for first and second moments of your game.

Comment: **Note:** To find $\Bbb E[X_k^2]$ use the following: $$\begin{align}\Bbb E[X_k^2] &= \Bbb{Var}[X_k]+\Bbb E[X_k]^2 \\ &= V_k+E_k^2\end{align}$$